# Plot in 3d with wireframe in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot in 3d with wireframe, here is my code:

```
mecdf = function (nr, nc, x, u) # mecdf is the bivariate cumulative empiric function 
{  k = rep (TRUE, nr)
   for (j in 1:nc) k = k & (x [,j] <= u [j])
   sum (k) / nr
}

xc = round(runif(100), 2)
yc = round(runif(100), 2)
Da = cbind(xc, yc)

bcdfa<-rep(NA,100)
for (i in 1:100) {bcdfa[i]=mecdf(nrow(Da),ncol(Da),Da,Da[i,])}    
bcdfa

x<-cbind(xc,yc,bcdfa) # bcdfa is the value of the bcdfa in every (xc,yc) point



 ...........
```

Is it possible to use the wireframe or another function with these data to represent the bivariate cumulative distribution function ?

Comment: Is your question "find me the package `lattice` " or is it "how to dump these variables into the function `lattice:wireframe` " ?

Comment: my question is how to dump these variables into the function lattice:wireframe. Thank you

Comment: @QuintinCopete Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: All, or nearly all, 3D mesh/wireframe plotting tools require a regularized set of coordinates. You may need to use a tool such as `akima:interp` to generate values of `bcdfa` on a uniform grid. Alternatively, just plot points in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

```
library(akima)
library(plot3D)
 bcfoo<-interp(xc,yc,bcdfa)

 persp3D(bcfoo$x,bcfoo$y,bcfoo$z)
```

[image: the surface]

```
 #plot points to verify overall shape

 scatter3D(xc,yc,bcdfa)
```

[image: the data]